# osm_id in a shapefile vs. the uid and id attributes in an OSM file

Tags: python, shapefile, openstreetmap

I'm parsing an **OSM file** using the Python package `osmread`. The entities parsed have the following attributes `id`, `version`, `changeset`, `timestamp`, `uid`, and `tags`.

On the other hand, I have a **shapefile**, and I use the Python package `pyshp` to read it. I then get the following fields from this (road) shapefile:

```
    [('DeletionFlag', 'C', 1, 0),
    ['osm_id', 'N', 11, 0],
    ['name', 'C', 48, 0],
    ['ref', 'C', 16, 0],
    ['type', 'C', 16, 0],
    ['oneway', 'N', 1, 0],
    ['bridge', 'N', 1, 0],
    ['tunnel', 'N', 1, 0],
    ['maxspeed', 'N', 3, 0]]
```

My question is, if the road shapefile was obtained from the OSM file, which of the two attributes, `id` or `uid`, in the OSM file corresponds to the `osm_id` field in the shapefile?

Answer (score 2):

The `id` attribute and **not** the `uid` attribute of the OSM file corresponds to the `osm_id` in the shapefile.